# Eclipse, many projects and recreating development environment

Tags: eclipse

I'm playing with Eclipse. I've seen recommendations not to push to VCS anything from workspace directory, only the projects themselves. However this means that when building a development environment from scratch, you need to create a workspace and manually import all projects you need.

Is there any shortcut? Visual Studio uses solution files which have a list of projects, is there anything similar in Eclipse?

My projects usually are in python, javascript, C++ and so on... so I'd like to avoid anything language-specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `File->Export->Team Project Set` to share your projects with others in the team so that they can set up the projects in their workspaces by performing `File->Import->Team Project Set`. An official step by step instruction (using CVS) on this can be found [here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-cvs-project-set.htm). A video tutorial using svn is available [here](http://eclipseone.wordpress.com/2010/01/25/checkout-multiple-projects-automatically-into-your-eclipse-workspace/).

Comment: @liori - I added an additional link for svn. Hope this gets you going :)